# WinForm DateTimePicker with Entity Framework Databinding

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datetimepicker

I have a WinForm `DateTimePicker` and `BindingSource` with context objects. When I add the first record, it works fine (`context.savechanges()`), but the second time - if I use the same form without reopening it - it fails due to "DateTime2 error". I figured out that the local context is not being updated with `DateTimePicket.value`. It shows some 01/01/0001 12:00 AM as per the below code even after resetting

```
datetimepicker.value = datetime.today();
MessageBox.Show(purchaseDateDateTimePicker.Text);  //will give you the correct date
MessageBox.Show(_context.Purchases.Find(0).PurchaseDate.ToString());  // will give 01/01/0001 12:00 AM
_context.SaveChanges(); //failed due to this datetime2 error
```

I tested it by changing the model `datatime` type to a nullable (datetime?) and it worked, but I need a non-nullable type and set properly from the screen.

Is there any proper solution for this?

Comment: In this code fragment, you don't assign the datepicker's value to any entity's property. Please show a working example.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sorry, that was a misunderstanding. It is fixed now (by the OP) and the rest of of my edit was helpful, I suppose.